# write_characteristic_error, writeCharacteristic failed, null, null

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to develop an app with flutter which should be able to connect via bluetooth to a GPS device with the package flutter_blue_plus. I'm currently getting this error

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(write_characteristic_error, writeCharacteristic failed, null, null)

when I try to send bytes to get the data I need. I'm still new at this and for what I've seen, bluetooth connections is not the most simple thing to implement.

I'm also doing it based from this [sample](https://github.com/lupyuen/flutter-blue-sample/tree/master/lib)

This error shows up when I try to use the `write()` function.

The code block that is giving me the problem. Is there anything I might be missing here?

```
List<Widget> _buildServiceTiles(List<BluetoothService> services) {
    return services
        .map(
          (s) => ServiceTile(
            service: s,
            characteristicTiles: s.characteristics
                .map(
                  (c) => CharacteristicTile(
                    characteristic: c,
                    onReadPressed: () async {
                      List data = await c.read();
                      print('DATA: ${data.toString()}');
                      // List<int> value = await c.read();
                      // _parseHr(value); //parse bytes
                      // print(_getRandomBytes());
                    },
                    onWritePressed: () async {
                      await c.write(_getRandomBytes(), withoutResponse: true);
                      // await c.read();
                    },
                    onNotificationPressed: () async {
                      await c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying);
                      await c.read();
                    },
                    descriptorTiles: c.descriptors
                        .map(
                          (d) => DescriptorTile(
                            descriptor: d,
                            onReadPressed: () async {
                              // List<int> value = await c.read();
                              d.read();
                            },
                            onWritePressed: () async {
                              d.write(_getRandomBytes());
                              // print(_sendBytes());
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }
```

Comment: did you got any solution for this issue?

Comment: yeah, turns out I had to speak with the company that developed the bluetooth device and told me how to get the data, since it was all in hexadecimal. I had to convert it afterwards. My issue and solution may not be useful for anyone. So I might close this one